# How to Associate Function Libraries to  QTP Script?

Tags: vbscript, automated-tests, qtp

How to Associate Function library with QTP script outsie the QTP environment.

your help is highly appreciated.

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are 4 Different Ways to Associate Function Libraries to your QTP Script.
Please refer this [Link](http://www.automationrepository.com/2011/09/associate-function-library-to-qtp-script/)

Comment: @user473442 if an answer is helpful you should consider voting it up (it's funny seeing an accepted answer with 0 votes, so I rectified that).

Comment: but there is another problem when trying to Use (LoadFunctionLibrary) with Libraries on QC ...run time error popup will be generated.