# Error in Library File

Tags: vb.net, function, qtp

I am new to QTP, and my question is perhaps silly, but i don't know how to proceed.

I have written script and saved in the function library as below (simple one):

```
Function startup()
    ' code for opening a excel,browser
End Function
```

I have associated this one with my test (say for "test1"), but when i calling the function

```
call startup()
```

it is throwing an error as

"Error in library file, your function library may not be valid".

It would be of great help if you could explain me how to call a set of codes(functions) in a function library without passing any arguments?

Comment: Have you associated that FL with your test?

Comment: Please check this answer ..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11071302/how-to-associate-function-libraries-to-qtp-script/11077049#11077049

Comment: Yes,I have associated my FL.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comment, make sure the Function library is associated with the test at File->Settings under resources section add the function library.

Try changing the function definition to:

```
Public Function Startup()
```

Still an error:  comment out all the code in the function (in fact all code in the library) and try to run. If it works then start to uncomment parts of the code in the library till you find the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the function libraries which is created is associated with the test properly.